# Android code for showing driving directions and updating the directions as per user/device movement

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-2.3-gingerbread

Hi  everybody i am making an application that required driving directions in it. Same as navigation feature provided by the google. But i am not able to find any solution for this. If anybody knows about some alternative of google navigation system that can be used in android application then plz help me

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using, And it is actually google navigation.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+latitude_cur+","+longitude_cur+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );     
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```